# Android Bitmap

Tags: android, java, bitmap

Правильно ли я пытаюсь делать? Приложение компилируется, но при запуске падает.

```
ImageView user_image;
user_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap imageNews = getBitmapFromURL("http://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/middle/0/aa/priroda-nebo-oblaka-peyzazh-5908.jpg");
user_image.setImageBitmap(imageNews);
```

Класс *getBitmapFromURL*

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Log.v("123654","123654");
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("2345623456","2345623456");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: А что в LogCat выводит при падении?

Comment: @batazor, в основном потоке же с сетью работаете.

Comment: @bartwell выводит это https://gist.github.com/batazor/14c42b8c5de7112cf2a4

Comment: @batazor, NetworkOnMainThreadException. Это значит, что SuperCreeper ответил вам правильно.

Comment: @BArtWell То есть я должен выполнить эти действия в отдельном потоку, например с помощью AsyncTask?

Comment: @batazor, да, вам нужно вынести этот код в отдельный поток. AsyncTask для этого вполне подойдет. Можно немного проще, с помощью new Thread(new Runnable() {}).start();

Comment: Только, поправьтесь, getBitmapFromURL() это не класс.